# Is this theorem sufficient to prove the existence of a 1-to-1 mapping of $\mathbb{R}$ onto $\left(0,1\right)\subset\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

This is from the chapter *Construction of the System of Real Numbers* in [The Fundamentals of Mathematics, Volume 1](https://archive.org/stream/MyStuff38/Behnke%2C%20Bachmann%2C%20Fladt%20%26%20Suss%20%5BEds.%5D%20-%20Fundamentals%20of%20Mathematics%20Vol.1%2C%20The%20Real%20Number%20System%20and%20Algebra%5BMIT%20Press%2C%20555p%5D#page/n7/mode/2up).

> In general, two sets are said to be equivalent if either of them can
>   be mapped one-to-one onto the other. Thus the finite sets are defined
>   as those sets that are equivalent to the segments $A_{n}.$ For convenience,
>   the empty set $\emptyset,$ which contains no elements at all, is
>   also said to be a finite set. In an infinite set $M,$ namely a set
>   which is not finite, it is easy to determine a set which is equivalent
>   to the set $\mathbb{N}$ of all natural numbers: for if $f$ is a
>   mapping which to each non-empty subset $X$ of the set $M$ assigns
>   an element of $f\left[X\right]$ of the subset $X,$ the sets $M_{1},M_{2},\dots$
>   can be defined recursively by $M_{1}=\left\{ f\left[M\right]\right\} ,$$M_{n^{\prime}}=M_{n}\cup\left\{ f\left[M-M_{n}\right]\right\} ,$
>   and then the union of the $M_{n}$ provides us with the desired subset
>   $\mathbb{N^{*}}.$

Is this theorem sufficient to justify the claim that $\mathbb{R}$ can be mapped one-to-one onto $\left(0,1\right)\subset\mathbb{R}$?

It only seems to say that we can map $\mathbb{N}$ real numbers at a time.

Comment: If your book claims that $\varnothing$ is only finite "for convenience", I would start looking for another book.

Comment: The fact that any infinite set has a subset with the same cardinality as $\mathbb{N}$ does not seem to have much relation to the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ and the interval $(0,1)$ have the same cardinality. It is not that difficult to find a bijection to establish the latter fact. It is even easier if you use the Schroder-Bernstein theorem (that injections both ways are sufficient).

Comment: In this particular chapter, they have yet to introduce the number 0.  They, therefore have no way to "prove" $\varnothing$ to be finite.  There are many different ways to develop the foundational structures of mathematics.  Beginning with the natural numbers with 1 as the non-successor is not the most common, but it is a worthwhile exercise.

Comment: @StevenThomasHatton But the extract you give starts by talking about sets! The construction of the reals comes well after set theory.

Comment: @almagest I am aware of that.  I am reviewing my notes on the chapter, and the question occurred to me.  The theorem is not central to the development, so it isn't expanded upon.  These notes are written using my own notation, and deviate significantly from the wording and details of the proofs in the book.  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HRn2OJJV8OiJNBvDBTpsSjDL0VHdLvbE

Comment: @StevenThomasHatton  So what do you make of my first comment above?

Comment: @almagest The first chapter in the book covers the basics of logic, set theory, relations, etc.  In that chapter we are told "The cardinal number of a finite set can simply be identified with the number of elements in the set."  Since, in the current context, there is no number $0$, there is no way to assign a unique cardinal number to the empty set.  The definition of a finite set given above relies on segments of $\mathbb{N}_1$.  There are many ways to develop various fields of mathematics. Compare MTW's Gravitation to Edwards's Advanced Calculus of Several Variables.

Comment: Even if you define the natural numbers as starting from $1$, and even if I don't know *exactly* what does the text mean by "segments $A_n$", if you define the initial segments by $A_n=\{m\in\Bbb N\mid m<n\}$, then $A_1$ is empty, and you don't have to make this convenience remark.

Comment: @AsafKaragila The segments are $A_n=\{m\in\Bbb N\mid m\le n\}$.  Your proposed definition is less intuitive and more complicated.  I don't see it as any less arbitrary than the fiat definition given in the book.  In applied math, I typically use the term "finite" to mean non-zero and bounded.  As in "finite displacement."  I encourage you to examine the book before rejecting it.  Unfortunately, the extraordinary accomplishment of translating the book to English was not flawless.  There are some nasty errors.  See Page 102 of the above linked copy for the current context.

Comment: @almagest I'm starting to believe the theorem under discussion will give us most, if not all of what we need to justify the continuous mapping.  Intuitively, we might think of the natural numbers as mile-markers (yes, I am American), and the real numbers as the highway.  If we have an ordered mapping of the natural numbers, "and everything between them", then we have a continuous mapping of the reals $\ge 1$ (in this case).  That is what the subsequent discussion in the book provides.